# What's the difference between onComplete and flatMap of Future?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, reactive-programming

I'm writing a Scala application using ReactiveMongo driver. The methods that access to the db return always `Future[T]`. Are the following pieces of code equivalent?

(With `onComplete`)

```
val results: Future[List[Tag]] = Tags.all.toList
results onComplete {
    case Success(list) => //do something with list
    case Failure(t) => //throw the error
}
```

(With `flatMap`)

```
Tags.all.toList.flatMap(list => //do something with list)
```

What's the difference?

The flatMap doesn't throw the Failure?? And the `flatMap` is a callback like `onComplete` or wait until the `Tags.all.toList` statement doesn't complete?

Comment: It is obvious from the signature: likewise Try monad, `flatMap` is not concerned with failures. It is what the monad is about: you pass any errors intact and apply your operations only if there is no error in the pipe.  Only in the end you are advised to catch both errors and successes

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When in doubt, follow the types.

`onComplete` returns `Unit`, it allows you to do something with the `Future` result, but it won't return a value

`flatMap` allow you do something with the list **and** return a new `Future`

So `flatMap` is much more powerful as it allows you to chain multiple futures, doing something with their values along the way, and handling the failure case only at the very end. To use Erik Meijer's words: "it guides you through the happy path".

So for instance you can do

```
val finalFuture = results
 .flatMap(x => /* do something and return a future */)
 .flatMap(y => /* do something else and return a future */)
 .flatMap(z => /* do something else and return a future */)
 .map(myresult => /* do something */)
```

If something goes wrong along the way, the chain is broken early and you'll get the first error occurred.

This allows for an even nicer syntax

```
 val finalFuture = for {
    x <- results
    y <- /* do something and return a future */
    z <- /* do something and return a future */
 } yield something(z)
```

If you need to handle the failure case, you can now use `onComplete`, or - even better - simply return the `Future` as it already contains the information on whether the async computation succeeded or not.

Comment: In this example, finalFuture returns a Future[Nothing] no matter what the type of something(z) is. What if you need to pass something(z): T to something expecting T?

Comment: @Azeli the type of finalFuture depends on the return type of something. If something returns a A it's Future[A]. If you need to pass a value of type A to a function you need to do it in the context of Future, I.e. in a for-comprehension or directly in a map. Alternatively you can block the future and await for its result, but that's rarely a good strategy